# Should I replace my hardisk. Since the past few weeks when I boot my system, it becomes read protected and I have to do a manual fsck

Tags: mount, hard-drive

This is the output from a diagnostic I ran. The overall health self assessment is passing but at the end I do see some errors where some partitions are not accessible. I am using a dual boot system, but I don't think its because of that. Should I replace my hdd?

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-135-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    383UTTA7T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 861e80b73
Firmware Version: AX0P3D
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Mar 19 10:41:00 2021 PKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 112) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 234) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   100   100   050    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   100   100   001    -    1757
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   050    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   078   078   000    -    8964
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2475
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    3923
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    101
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   095   095   000    -    51260
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   100   100   000    -    42 (Min/Max 13/48)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       -O--CK   082   082   000    -    7498
241 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    15639127103
242 Total_LBAs_Read         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    9937910969
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O     51  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O     64  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (64 sectors)
Device Error Count: 484 (device log contains only the most recent 256 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.
    
    
    
        SCT Error Recovery Control:
               Read: Disabled
              Write: Disabled
    
    Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
    Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
    0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 2) ==
    0x01  0x008  4            2475  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
    0x01  0x010  4            8964  ---  Power-on Hours
    0x01  0x018  6     15639127103  ---  Logical Sectors Written
    0x01  0x020  6       292664593  ---  Number of Write Commands
    0x01  0x028  6      9937910969  ---  Logical Sectors Read
    0x01  0x030  6       195701542  ---  Number of Read Commands
    0x02  =====  =               =  ===  == Free-Fall Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x02  0x010  4            3923  ---  Overlimit Shock Events
    0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x03  0x008  4            8875  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
    0x03  0x010  4            7498  ---  Head Flying Hours
    0x03  0x018  4           51260  ---  Head Load Events
    0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
    0x03  0x028  4              35  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
    0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
    0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x04  0x008  4             484  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
    0x04  0x010  4               1  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
    0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x05  0x008  1              42  ---  Current Temperature
    0x05  0x010  1              37  N--  Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x018  1              34  N--  Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x020  1              48  ---  Highest Temperature
    0x05  0x028  1              13  ---  Lowest Temperature
    0x05  0x030  1              42  N--  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x038  1              28  N--  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
    0x05  0x040  1              37  N--  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x048  1              30  N--  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
    0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
    0x05  0x058  1              55  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
    0x05  0x060  4               9  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
    0x05  0x068  1              15  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
    0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x06  0x008  4           39387  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
    0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
    0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
    0x07  0x008  1              14  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                    |||_ C monitored condition met
                                    ||__ D supports DSN
                                    |___ N normalized value
    
    SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
    ID      Size     Value  Description
    0x0001  4            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
    0x0002  4            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
    0x0003  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
    0x0004  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
    0x0005  4            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
    0x0006  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
    0x0007  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
    0x0008  4            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
    0x0009  4            2  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
    0x000a  4            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
    0x000b  4            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
    0x000d  4            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
    0x000f  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
    0x0010  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
    0x0012  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
    0x0013  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you still can take off the data you need and replace the hard drive. Very soon.

Comment: Thought so. Made the backup last night. Now going out to replace my internal hdd with a new ssd.

Comment: If you like the answer do not forget to accept it thanks.